# Problem loading CentOS on Linux Virtual Box

Tags: centos, virtualbox, window, container

I am trying to install CentOS 07-1810 on my new Virtualbox and I was getting an error message. It looks like the software is bigger than the available size of my System hard disk, but being a new user of linux, I am not sure what the enclose error message means and how to correct it.

The Cent0S 07 is about 4.67 GB and the overall available space on my Laptop is 4GB with 3.83 usable space.

Question: Is there a smaller size OS that I use on Linux Virtual box? 
Question: I am particularly interested in RedHat Operating system for Linux, any recommendation?

Please see enclosed for the error message I am getting.

David[image]

Comment: Saw on the Virtualbox forum that downgrading Virtualbox seems to eliminate the error, can you try that?  (ref: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=93990)